# Multiple category join

Tags: php, mysql

I need to find all the businesses by category and by city

I have 3 tables:

**1. Business:**

[image: business table]

**2. Category:**

[image: category table]

**3.Business_con_Category:**

[image: Business_con_Category table]

I get variables category and city form url:
`http://domain.com/search.php?category=4&city=4`

How can I find all the businesses by 2 variables ? Do I need to use Join ?

thanks you.

Comment: This some sort of quiz or homework?

Comment: No, it's a problem I can not solve in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
SELECT * FROM Business b
INNER JOIN Business_con_Category bc ON b.ID=bc.Business_ID
WHERE bc.Category_ID=4 AND b.city=4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in SQL:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name FROM Business b
    INNER JOIN Business_con_Category bc ON bc.Business_ID = b.ID
WHERE
    bc.Category_ID = ? AND b.city = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have depicted above, this is what they call `many-to-many relationship`  and you definitely need to use JOIN in order to merge tables.  Your question is already addressed here as i think

[Many-to-many relationships examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples)