# how to simplify this mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to simplify the query below. As you can for each of the users row I have to run 3 queries for datastore.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users"
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
 if($row['first_dataid'] != 0) {
   $d1 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM datastore WHERE dataid = '".$row['first_dataid']."'"));
  }
 if($row['second_dataid'] != 0) {
   $d2 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM datastore WHERE dataid = '".$row['second_dataid']."'"));
  }
 if($row['third_dataid'] != 0) {
   $d3 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM datastore WHERE dataid = '".$row['third_dataid']."'"));
  }

}
```

I have a table `datastore`

```
dataid, name, description, createdate
```

Then I have many different tables which link to `dataid` of `datastore` e.g.

Users

```
userid, username, first_dataid, second_dataid, third_dataid
```

I was thinking of mysql join but not sure as if it were one column then I could try something like

```
select u.* from users u left join datastore d ON d.dataid = u.first_datastoreid 
AND ..??
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. You may also want to consider whether your design is properly normalized.

Comment: How are you going to use the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select u.*,
COALESCE(d1.name, d2.name, d3.name) AS name 
from users u 
left join datastore d1 ON d1.dataid = u.first_datastoreid 
left join datastore d2 ON d2.dataid = u.second_datastoreid 
left join datastore d3 ON d3.dataid = u.third_datastoreid
```

The `COALESCE` line gets you whichever one is filled in. (Thanks to @DigitalChris)

You should really normalize this data though, you shouldn't have fields called 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: [Coalesce()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) is much nicer than recursive IFNULL()s

Comment: I like the idea of incrementing 'F's though

Comment: You would have a new table for userDataStore that would contain the user id and the data id. Then do a join to that, then join to datastore.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how you are going to use the data and therefore i cannot recommend you the best query.

In response to your last query attempt at the end of question - this will give you all associated datastores with 1 join, each on separete row:

```
SELECT u.*, d.dataid, d.name -- put columns you need here
  FROM users u 
  LEFT JOIN datastore d 
    ON d.dataid in (u.first_datastoreid, u.second_dataid, u.third_dataid)
```

For better normalisation consider using many-to-many relationship https://stackoverflow.com/a/2923921/350021

Answer (score -1):

You can try this sql query

```
select u.* from users u 
left join datastore d1 ON d1.dataid = u.first_dataid
left join datastore d2 ON d2.dataid = u.second_dataid
left join datastore d3 ON d3.dataid = u.third_dataid
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM Users
LEFT JOIN datastore datastore1 ON Users.first_dataid = datastore1.dataid
LEFT JOIN datastore datastore2 ON Users.second_dataid = datastore2.dataid
LEFT JOIN datastore datastore3 ON Users.third_dataid = datastore3.dataid
```