# What many-to-many relation I have to chose?

Tags: database-design

When I do have a table:

user: userID

product: productID

and a table named user_product: userID, productID

what would look like the many to many relation concerning using 1, 1..m , 0..m  and so on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the application.

Is a user always associated with product? Probably not, and if so, there is a '0..infinity' on the product side of the relation.

Is a product always associated with a user? Probably yes, and if so, there should be a '1..infinity' on the user side of the relation.

Comment: what about the primary keys productID and userID, are they automatically foreign keys in the relation tableß

Comment: u meant like user 1 - 1..infinite user_product 0..infinite - 1 product - right?

Comment: Not automatically. You have to specify that in your DDL (SQL statements to create tables)

Comment: What I described before was for the conceptual model. For the physical model, no row in the join table can exist without bot a userid AND a productId. So user 1 - 0...Infinite user_product 0...infinite - 1 product. I hope this is not confusing.