# SQL storing large amount of data for each user

Tags: mysql, sql, user-data

I'm developing a website, where people will be able to play small games. At the end of each game the user will be given a score, which I wish to store in a MySQL database with a timestamp. This will allow me to present the data in a nice way further down the line.

I use a Facebook login system, so I currently have a table which consists of User ID, Name, and a Facebook ID. Currently I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID------Name------UID
 1      Bob     123123
 2      Marley   23134
```

Then, for each user I will need something like this:

```
Game1Time    Game1Score   Game2Time   Game2Score etc....
  3292          400           10           7824
   129           32          101            231
```

I've looked at some of the other related posts, and it seems that people generally think it's a bad idea to have a table for each user, but to me, that seems like the easiest way.

I could also do something like this, where I store all data in one table:

```
ID------Name------UID-------Game1Time-----Game1Score----Game2Time-----Game2Score etc...
 1      Bob     123123      3291, 129      400, 32       10, 101         7824, 231
 2      Marley   23134
```

But this seems like it might cause problems, when people play a lot of the same game.

I feel like I'm missing some smart way of doing this, so if you have any recommendation, please tell me. I'm fairly new to SQL so I'm probably missing something stupid

Comment: Look up database normalization.  User table, Games table, and then a UserGames table to store the ids and the time and score...

Comment: Your best bet will be to have a relational database with a many to many relationship. That way it will be across multiple tables joined based on the ID's and you won't hit problems when you add more games.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, I'll look into to these right away

Comment: @sgeddes Database normalization seems like the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recommend some normalization here.

Your users table is fine. Create a games table to store information about games. Create a table that combines information about users and games and results. Something on the lines of:

```
create table users (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(100),
  uid int
);

create table games (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(100)
);

create table users_games (
  id int primary key,
  userid int,
  gameid int,
  startdate datetime,
  enddate datetime,
  score bigint,
  constraint fk_users_games_userid foreign key (userid) references users(id),
  constraint fk_users_games_gameid foreign key (gameid) references games(id)
);
```

Using startdate and enddate you can calculate the time user was on the game. You can run statistics about distinct users on a given hour of the day and a whole bunch more reporting based on users_games table.

You can create indexes on users_games as you desire. That table can grow big, no problem. You can use partitioning by userid if you like or archive data systematically as the data gets too stale to be used on a regular basis.

Example schema is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/315a5.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. This solved my problem

Comment: correct answer but... i would avoid the use of a dedicated field as primary key even if it is not an identity (or whatever the name is on mysql): https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-putting-an-identity-column-on-every-table

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be the following:
So basically you have two tables one with the uid that you can use to search for the other info you need.
Plus you save stuff where needed

```
ID------Name------UID-------
 1      Bob     123123       
 2      Marley   23134


ID-----UID------GameTime-----GameScore
1      123123    3291           400
2      123123    129             32
3      234134    10             101       
4      432123    7824           231
```

Comment: This looks like it might work. Just one question: Wouldn't the second table become so large, that it would take a lot computer effort to search through the entire table?.. Or am I underestimating the capabilities of a MySQL database?

Comment: Hi Malt depending on the amount of games and user you might have to use some other db but for now it works fine. Mysql is quite strong. Next to that if you set your lookup indices correct nothing to worry about

Answer (score 2):

Have three tables - Users, Games, Results.

Users stores a record for each user, and has the columns UID and the user's name.

Games stores a record for each game, and has the columns GID (Game ID), and the game's name.

Results stores a record for each *game played*, and has the columns UID, GID, Timestamp, and Score.

That way, you can store as many scores for as many games as you like, against any user.

Relational data!

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use a relational database with a many to many relationship on the UserGameMaps table

User

```
ID------Name------UID-------
 1      Bob     123123       
 2      Marley   23134
```

GameData

```
ID------GameTime-----GameScore
1       3291, 129     400,32
2       10, 101       7824, 231
3       etc etc
```

UserGameMaps

```
ID-----UserID------GameId
1      1           1   
2      1           2
3      2           3
```

A good example of this can be found of StackOverflow here: [Many-to-many relationships examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples)

This would enable you to keep your game data and users entirely seperate. This would help to resolve any further issues that you may encounter if you want to add more games, allow multiple scores for a single game. ect. If you had all of your data on one table and you wanted to add your new game you would have to manually add another column onto the end of the user table everytime you wanted to add or remove a game.