# Retrieving many related information

Tags: php, optimization, dao

I am working on an admin system that allows users to manage their brewery profile and beer inventory.

I have three related tables: Users, Breweries, and Beers. There is a 1-to-1 relationship between Users and Breweries, and a 1-to-many relationship between Breweries and Beers. Each table has a corresponding DAO: UserDAO, BreweryDAO, and BeerDAO, respectively.

If a user wants to add a beer, for example, they would go to a page, `beer.php?brewery=123` where `123` is the ID of the brewery that this new beer will be added to. If a user wants to update a beer, they would go to the same page, e.g. `beer.php?id=456`, where `456` is the ID of the beer that will be edited.

Now, when I go to the beer page, I need two pieces of information: the brewery and the beer, if they are editing. I also need to ensure that the brewery belongs to the logged-in user.

I can think of two ways of doing this:

**Option 1**: Using many queries with no JOINs

```
// get relevant data for adding a new beer
if (isset($_GET['brewery'])) {
    $brewery = $breweryDAO->getBreweryById($_GET['brewery']);
    // check if no brewery or brewery doesn't belong to user
    if (!$brewery || $brewery->user_id != $currentUser->id) {
        // error
    }
// get relevant data for editing a beer
} elseif (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $beer = $beerDAO->getBeerById($_GET['id']);
    if ($beer) {
        $brewery = $breweryDAO->getBreweryById($beer->id);
    }
    // check if no beer, no brewery, or brewery doesn't belong to user 
    if (!$beer || empty($brewery) || $brewery->user_id != $currentUser->id) {
        // error
    }
} else {
    // error
}
```

**Option 2**: Using a single queries with JOINs

```
// get relevant data for adding a new beer
if (isset($_GET['brewery'])) {
    // get user's brewery
    $brewery = $breweryDAO->getBreweryByIdAndUser($_GET['brewery'], $currentUser->id);
    // check if no brewery was found 
    if (!$brewery) {
        // error
    }
// get relevant data for editing an existing beer
} elseif (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // get user's beer AND brewery information all together
    $beer = $beerDAO->getBeerByIdAndUser($_GET['id'], $currentUser->id);
    // check if no beer was found
    if (!$beer) {
        // error
    }
} else {
    // error
}
```

When retrieving a beer, is it better to make separate queries (**Option 1**) or use single JOINed queries (**Option 2**) ? My concern is about which would be a better approach to querying multiple information that depend on each other. I usually do **Option 1**, but it can get pretty messy the more relationships there are. I am not too concerned about speed. Is there another way to structure my code as both options seem messy?

Comment: what you could do is a pivot table `brewery_user` which have  foreign keys brewery_id ref id in brewery, and user_id maps to the user id. Then you can query this to get the users breweries to then check etc so a many to many relation etc have  look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples for a MTM

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add a beer, you actually want to add something to a brewery. So I would change the structure of the application and create a brewery.php?id=breweryid for editing breweries.

This would be a possible step, to keep your files a little bit smaller (no need for the outer elseif{}else{} structure as you only have to directly validate the given id) and more focused on the objects. At least you don't have to check if you actually want to interact with the beer or the brewery.

The next step would be to not load the complete brewery-object just to compare the user-id to the currentUser. You could simply create a method like

```
/**
* @param int $breweryId
* @param int $userId
* @return boolean
*/
public function breweryBelongsToUser($breweryId, $userId){
    // return false if no entry in database
}
```