# How to use list in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I am working on database design for my web based application. 
I have some experience of MongoDB but no experience of MySQL.

I want to store projects information in database with list of users working on the project.

In **MongoDB** i can do this like:

```
{
 A :{
     ID : 01,
     NAME : A,
     TYPE : T1,
     USERS : [userA, UserB, UserC]
    }
}
```

I Dont know how to do this in **MySQL** .

```
ID  |  NAME |  TYPE  |  USERS
01      A       T1       ?          (userA, UserB, UserC)
02      B       T2       ?          (userX, UserY, UserZ)
```

Now in MYSQL, I want to assign list of users for each project.

Comment: If a user can work on multiple projects, this should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples

Answer (score 1):

In your transition from mongodb to mysql you will miss the flexibility of mongodb while designing your application. 
I can recommend you taking a look to [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1423900839) where you can learn about normalization.

---

Your example doesn't give enough information about if this a relation of one to many(A user works just on one project) or many to many (A user works in many projects). Using "userA", "userB", etc. as identifiers for users i would do this for both approches that i said:

1 to Many. -

```
create table projects(Id integer PRIMARY KEY,  Name varchar(20), Type varchar(20));
create table users (Id varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY, Project_Id integer, FOREIGN KEY fk_proj(Project_Id)  REFERENCES projects(Id));
```

---

```
mysql> describe projects;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Name  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Type  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
mysql> describe users;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id         | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Project_Id | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Where users(Poject_Id) references projects(Id)

I used varchar in the id attribute just for the case.

How you query this in MySQL?
Choose one from below

```
 select p.Id, Name, Type, u.Id as Users from projects as p JOIN users as u  on p.Id=u.Project_Id;
```

Or

```
 select p.Id, Name, Type, u.Id as Users from projects as p, users as u  where p.Id=u.Project_Id;
```

Same result

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+
| Id | Name  | Type  | Users |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | ProjA | TypeA | UserA |
|  1 | ProjA | TypeA | UserB |
|  1 | ProjA | TypeA | UserC |
|  2 | ProjB | TypeB | Userx |
|  2 | ProjB | TypeB | UserY |
|  2 | ProjB | TypeB | UserZ |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

---

Many to Many.- For M to M relationship instead of using the project identifier in the users table, you will create a separate table holding both tables primary key (project.Id, and users.Id), and making that tuple of attributes the pk of this table.

```
create table projects(Id integer PRIMARY KEY,  Name varchar(20), Type varchar(20));
create table users (Id varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY);
create table projects_users(Id_Project integer not null, Id_User varchar(11) not null, PRIMARY KEY pk_projects_users(Id_Project, Id_User));
```

---

```
mysql> describe projects;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Name  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Type  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
mysql> describe users;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id    | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
mysql> describe projects_users;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id_Project | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Id_User    | varchar(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

---

Again, choose one way to query this.

```
SELECT p.Id, Name, Type, pu.Id_User as User FROM projects as p join projects_users as pu ON p.Id=pu.Id_Project;
SELECT p.Id, Name, Type, pu.Id_User as User FROM projects as p, projects_users as pu WHERE p.Id=pu.Id_Project;
```

And the result

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+
| Id | Name  | Type  | User  |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | ProjA | TypeA | UserA |
|  1 | ProjA | TypeA | UserB |
|  1 | ProjA | TypeA | UserC |
|  1 | ProjA | TypeA | UserY |
|  2 | ProjA | TypeA | Userx |
|  2 | ProjA | TypeA | UserY |
|  2 | ProjA | TypeA | UserZ |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

---

As you can see queries on mysql are quite different from queries on mongodb. I hope i made my self clear with this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a many to many relation, table project_user with id, project_id, user_id.
Or save user as a coma separated string and handle the change to list on your code.