# Multiple foreign key value

Tags: mysql, database

I have two table:

1. **tags** (lookup table)

   - tagId (primary key, AI)
   - tagName

**E.g.**

```
tagId | tagName
  1   |  Java   
  2   |  Sql
  3   |  OOP
```

2. **document**

   - docId (Primary key)
   - docName
   - tagId (Foreign Key)

**Example of how it is now**

```
docId | docName   | tagId
  1   |  a.txt    |   2
  2   |  b.pdf    |   1
  3   |  aa.xlsx  |   6
```

**Example of how i wanted**

```
docId | docName   |  tagId
  1   |  a.txt    |   2,3
  2   |  b.pdf    |   1
  3   |  aa.xlsx  |   6,1,7
```

So a document may have multiple tags, and in the column `tagId` (table **document**), the value will be stored is id seperated by commas ( **,** )

So how do i insert the data as it will only allow 1 `tagId` in table **document**? Because the user will input an autocomplete multiple tagging in html input text.

Comment: You'd need to [normalise](http://www.w3schools.in/dbms/database-normalization) your schema. Also have a look at [Many to Many Relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2923809/2298301). Effectively, this will imply removing `tagId` from `documents` and creating a new table that only contains `(docId, tagId)` combination.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena firstly, is it better if there is 3 table (tag, document, tag&document) or 2 table (tag, document) but with multiple rows with 1 tag id per row? secondly, if i have 3 table, does it mean when i wanted to display it to the user, i have to use `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Number of tables depends upon how interconnected your data is. Generally speaking, 3NF should be good for most purposes - you may read through the linked documentation to know more about it. In this particular case though, having three tables is sufficient to achieve a 3NF. `JOIN`s will make it easier to write the queries (if you want to fetch all the linked data in a single query). Again, the other post from the previous comment has some examples too.