# How to select multiple values from one MySQL table column with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table name `data_car`. The table data looks like this:

```
id   name      car
1    john      BMW, Toyota 
2    terry     Nixan, Toyota
```

My question how to select specific data from car. For example I have a combobox title car containing Toyota, BMW, Nissan, and I select Toyota so "name" person containing the value Toyota will show in my program.

The output I want is as follows:

```
name: john      car:toyota    payment:$1000
```

But unfortunately when I select toyota in the combobox the result is always BMW, and always shows up like this:

```
name : john    car:toyota,BMW   payment:$1000
```

My question is can I just select the toyota value from that column?

Comment: yeah ... that's why you should avoid `,` separated values in columns. try normalizing your table first

Comment: You can perform string manipulation on the data you select, which is probably better done in PHP than in SQL.  But why not fix the data design so that you don't have to perform hacks like this?

Comment: yup, its a relational DB, you need to place that on a different table and use JOINs.

Comment: I agree with @David, you can easily manipulate this string using explode on  php side, but make a change to your data design, if possible

Comment: youre querying for rows that contain "Toyota", how are you currelty doing that? Regardless, if you have any results, then you can just hardcode the string "toyota" in your HTML, since any results means that those columns do have the name Toyota in there. Unless you plan on rendering the other models as well. Then you would need to explode and iterate.

Comment: if its not possible to adapt the source table, which should only really have an atomic value in each cell, then you can use SQL to split the string based on the comma separator. this will inflate your row count as you will now have multiple records for each person who have more than 1 car

Comment: thnx for advise guys i know my database is teribble .my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform it with PHP like this:

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    $cars = explode(',', $value['car']);
    foreach ($cars as $car) {
        switch ($car) {
            case 'toyota':
                $values[$key]['car'] = $car;
                break;

            default:
                # code...
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

> I recommend you remodeling your database, transforming this data in a
>   many-to-many relationship.

**See also**:

- [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [Many-to-many relationships examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you re-design your database, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE drivers (
  driverid      int(11)       UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
  driver        varchar(64),
  PRIMARY KEY   (driverid)
);

CREATE TABLE cars (
  carid         int(11)       UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
  car           varchar(16),
  PRIMARY KEY   (carid)
);

CREATE TABLE driver_car (
  driverid      int(11),
  carid         int(11)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this as a select, and then join on to your costs table then you can split the string using SQL, you then put an outer reference and join onto costs. This way you could avoid recreating tables, although as stated above this would be a preferred method.

eg:

```
 SELECT id, name,
 PARSENAME(REPLACE(Split.a.value(',', 'VARCHAR(max)'),'-','.'),1) 'car' 
 FROM  
 (
 SELECT id, name,
 CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([car], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
 FROM   [table] 
 ) AS A 
 CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Comment: some consideration however will need to be given to how you will handle multiple values if a person has more than 1 car and what value from that range of cars you want to detail the cost for, as you will now have a row for every car per id and name - This is why it would have been better to have a car-id table which could have held the cars in line with id by a position for each car.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8 update:

```
SELECT name, REGEXP_SUBSTR(car, 'Toyota') as carname FROM data_car
```