# What is the correct datatype if I want to store array of IDs?

Tags: php, mysql, api, types

I'm developing a mobile application where I want to store in user's table a column to hold array of IDs for groups user's already joined. These IDs should be related to the group entry in groups table. I don't know if there's such a thing as a relational array of IDs, all I found is to make a comma separated values varchar column.  What is the best practice to achieve that? I'm using MYSQL and PHP for my API

Comment: You do that by creating a table which holds a User ID and a group ID in each dataset. The User ID and group ID  should be the primary Key of this table (together) and they both should be linked to their parent table with a foreign Key constraint. You should read about designing a relational database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard many-to-many relationship:

[image]

(I generated the diagram [here](https://app.quickdatabasediagrams.com/#/) )

If you Google how to create a many-to-many relationship in MySQL, you'll find plenty of tutorials and explanations. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2923921/2958070) is a decent looking one.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation, I will look for many-to-many relationship. Thank you again