# Optimal way to store follower and following MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have 2 tables one is `user` and another is `company`. Both have the following columns common while other columns are different.

```
id   email                name   
1    first@email.com      First user
2    second@email.com     Second User
3    third@email.com      Third User
```

Now a user can follow many companies but a company does not follow back user. Company should have data with users who follow them and a user should also store the companies they are following.

What is the simplest and optimal to make this happen on MySQL? Either should I create separate table for it or just add a column on existing tables with array of followers. Please answer assuming I have working level of knowledge on PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Definitely not option 2!! If you had a working knowledge of mysql, you would not consider that to be a possibility!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the tables `User` and `Company`. Let's suppose they contain these values:

`User`

| UserId | UserName | UserMail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | alice@mail.com |
| 2 | Bob | bob@mail.com |

`Company`

| CompanyId | CompanyName | CompanyAddress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Microsoft | Redmond |
| 2 | Apple | Cupertino |
| 3 | Google | Mountain View |

Then you should create a [many-to-many table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples) - *e.g.* let's call it `UserCompany` - which contains *at least* the columns `UserId` and `CompanyId` (coming from the first two tables).

Let's suppose that Alice follows Microsoft and Apple, and Bob follows Google. Your new `UserCompany` table will contain the following data:

| UserId | CompanyId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

> Company should have data of users who follow them

Here you are the query to get the data of the users that follow Microsoft:

```
SELECT u.UserName, u.UserMail
FROM User AS u
JOIN UserCompany AS uc ON u.UserId = uc.UserId
WHERE uc.CompanyId = 1
```

> User should also have data of companies they are following.

And here you are the query to get the data of the companies followed by Alice:

```
SELECT c.CompanyName, c.CompanyCity
FROM UserCompany AS uc
JOIN Company AS c ON c.CompanyId = uc.CompanyId
WHERE uc.UserId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to have a MANY-TO-MANY join table to link these 2 tables. You can do this with either 2 MANY-TO-MANY tables or a single one.

For example 2 table:

user_follows_company

```
ID    CompanyID UserID
----  ------ ---------
1     1      5
1     1      6
1     1      8
1     2      5
```

You can get the companies a user follows by using the following SQL:

`SELECT * FROM company c JOIN user_follows_company ufc on ufc.companyID = c.ID WHERE user = $USER_ID`

company_follows_user

```
ID    CompanyID UserID
----  --------- ---------
1     3         5
1     3         6
1     5         3
1     5         4
```

You can get the users a company follows by using the following SQL:

`SELECT * FROM user u JOIN company_follow_user cfu on cfu.userID = u.ID WHERE user = $USER_ID`

or you can do this with a single table and have a column that designates which direction is being followed:

follows_table

```
ID    CompanyID UserID     Initiator
----  --------- ---------  ---------
1     3         5          Company
1     3         6          Company
1     5         3          Company
1     5         4          Company
1     5         1          User
1     6         1          User
1     8         1          User
1     5         2          User
```

Note that storing the "initiator" as a string is not a good idea - it probably should be an int or an ENUM

To query on this table, do the following queries:

Companies a user follows:
`SELECT * FROM company c JOIN follows_table ft on ft.userID = c.ID WHERE user = $USER_ID AND ft.initiator = 'user'`

Users a company follows:
`SELECT * FROM user u JOIN follows_table ft on ft.userID = u.ID WHERE companyID = $$COMPANY_ID AND ft.initiator = 'company'`