# How to create a "connection" table with information of two separate tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I created two tables in my mysql database like such:

```
CREATE TABLE Representative(
   id varchar(15),
   name varchar(40),
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



CREATE TABLE Congress(
   congress_id int,
   total_members int,
   PRIMARY KEY(congress_id)
   )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

There are multiple congresses, and each one has different representatives in it. What I need to do is create another table that holds every representative that participated of a given congress. Note that one representative can be part of different congresses. I'm having troubles with foreign keys and don't really know the commands needed in order to create another table that connects the two other tables that already have been filled.

Comment: Is the `total_members` calculated off the number of Representatives associated with the Congress? And in terms of linking it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples

Comment: No, i have that information already, previous to collecting all the representatives and their infos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To represent this many-to-many relationship, you need another table, let's call it `Representatives_Congresses`.  It's often called a join table or junction table.

It will have two columns only, `representative_id`, and `congress_id`. Taken together, those columns will make up the primary key of your new table. They should also be set up as FKs.

To indicate that a representive was in a congress, insert a row into this table with the `id` values of the representative and the congress. To remove the representative from the congress, delete the row.