# Possible to list same item in multiple categories with PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a website which lists products in various categories and subcategories - fairly standard stuff. However, I now need to list the same product in multiple categories - how can I do this?

I'm using the code:

```
"SELECT * FROM ProductTable WHERE Category = 1"
```

I can get it to work by entering multiple numbers in the Category table i.e.`"1 2 3"` and using the code:

```
"SELECT * FROM ProductTable WHERE Category LIKE 1"
```

But this also returns products from category 10 and 11 (I have 20 categories).

I may be approaching this from the wrong angle but is there a way to make the code work?

Answer (score 1):

Since you no longer have a one-to-many relationship between categories and products you will need a new table to give the desired many-to-many relationship. Something like:

```
product_categories
------------------
category_id INT
product_id INT
```

Primary key: (category_id, product_id)

This will allow a product to belong to multiple categories in a normalized way instead of treating the Category field as a list of ids.

Comment: Thanks for this, but could you please elaborate? I have created a category table and changed the code to: "SELECT * FROM ProductTable INNER JOIN CategoryTable ON ProductTable.Category = CategoryTable.Category_ID WHERE Category_ID = 1" How do I get the same product into multiple categories?

Comment: Oh hang on, I think it's clicked - I need to use the tables to effectively create duplicate products? I.e. if using a single table I would need to create a duplicate line for each category that a product appears in (doubling or even tripling the size of the database) but using tables I just need to duplicate the ID?

Comment: searching for "many-to-many relationship" I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples which suggests I am on the right track, but need to create a third table to link the products and categories.

Answer (score 0):

To add to davidethell's answer, search and read about 'database normalization'. Good and simple relationships are key to relational databases. Wikipedia has a good article but there are many like it: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a thorough Google search now. I've altered my database to move elements such as the category name into different tables but I still need to understand how to get the same product to appear in multiple categories.

Answer (score 0):

OK so for anybody else trying to do this, here is my code:

"SELECT * FROM ProductTable INNER JOIN (LinkTable INNER JOIN CategoryTable ON LinkTable.intCategory = CategoryTable.intCategoryID) ON ProductTable.intProductID = LinkTable.intProduct WHERE LinkTable.intCategory = %s"

I have three tables:
The first is the product table, each product has a unique number which is the primary key.
The second is the category table, each category has a unique number which is the primary key.
I then created a third table with two columns; intProduct and intCategory as per David's answer above. It's this third table that stores the product/category listing, each product has a separate row for each category it is listed in.