# How to insert a record that points to many ids?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am a little confused on how to implement this table (still learning SQL). I would like to have 2 tables in relationship, but the column that is in relation to the other table needs to be able to take in MULTIPLE foreign keys. Here is the example I would like to try and do...

```
**Candidate Table**
(PK) id : int
(FK) exams : ??? <------ Multiple students many have multiple exams, so I need this column to contain MULTIPLE foreign keys. WHAT is the datatype that needs to be assigned to this column to take multiple foreign ids???
candidate_name : varchar (50)

**Exams Table**
(PK) id : int
exam subject : varchar (50)
exam_no : varchar(10)
nom_candidates : int
```

Is it POSSIBLE to do this in mySQL (even though it's a messy and confusing)? What would be the datatype of the column pointed in the first table in order to take multiple keys?

Comment: A single field should not hold multiple values, a central principle of database design. Investigate many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Hi. Time to read an introductory textbook on information modeling & relational databases.

Comment: I've read it already. It's just that sometimes I find breaking rules a "convenience" or so to say.... no offense mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigate many-to-many relationships.
[Here is a good example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples)

```
Create table that connects Candidate with Exam
** CandidateExam **
(FK) candidate_id: int
(FK) exam_id: int
```

Comment: Ok so I need 3 tables only just to do many-to-many (field) relationship between 2 tables? There's no other way is it? I was going to make an array, fill it up with foreign keys, then delete a foreign key out of the array if the student doesn't come to the exam. But I guess that won't work....omg...

Comment: A junction table is needed, to cross-match candidates to exams (and exams to candidates).

Comment: Alright, since I will be doing a junction table, I guess I might just add more ids in there to match in all the tables I need. yeah it's fine, I get it now.