# Find post with multiple tags

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project where projects have tags that are saved as "computer,windows" I would like it so if a user types "#Windows #Computer" it will find all posts that have both computer and windows

I tried `query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:tags , tags)', array(':tags' => $query))` and I set query to `$query = "computer,windows";` which returns 0 results even though I have one.

For getting it from hashtags to list I was thinking to remove spaces and replace "#" with "," so I can have "computer,windows"

While searching I found other questions but they didn't seem to support what I need since users can type any amount of tags they want others seemed to want a set amount of tags

Comment: Create a proper relational table that associates tags with posts and this is trivial. If you're using a comma-separated value you're violating the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Another suggestion is multiple `FIND_IN_SET` key words for each search term.

Comment: @tadman so I should create a table just for tags ?

Comment: At least one. If this is free text tags, then just the one (you may want to call it `post_tags`). If it is tags from a list then add an additional table with the valid tags (you'd call this table `tags`).

Comment: @Scuzzy I already saw that question, they seem to have a set amount of values also I tried that and it didn’t seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this : ( I'll make it with PDO )

```
// create a array of tags :
$arrayOfTags = [
    'computer',
    'windows',
    'another',
];
$query = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ';

// as much tags add ? to query 
$first = true;
for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayOfTags); ++$i) {
    if($first == true){
        $query .= "tags LIKE ? ";
    }else{
        $query .= "AND tags LIKE ? ";
    }
    $first = false;
}


// ad '%' to the beginning and the end of each tag name 
$arrayOfTags = array_map(function($value){
    return '%'.$value.'%';
} , $arrayOfTags);

// prepare and execute the query 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query ); 
$stmt->execute($arrayOfTags); 
//fetch the result
```

Code explanation:

1. First of all, we store all the tags in an array.
2. Next, for each tag, we add a query condition (like condition)
3. Next, we bind all the tags as query parameter.
4. We get the result

Comment: This gave me the idea to create this `DB::query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:tags , tags) AND FIND_IN_SET(:tag2 , tags)', array(':tags' => 'windows', ':tag2' => 'computer'))` but I don't know how i can make it support as many tags as they type

Comment: Why do not you make a loop like the above code . and add `FIND_IN_SET(:tag2 , tags)` to it as much as number of tags ?

Comment: The code I wrote in the post works fine. Because I tested it.
But the most common thing is to create a new table for tags

Comment: So have the posts table then a tags table? What would be in the tags table?

Comment: tags table can have just a column for name and another column for post_id , then you can find related tags by post_id , or you can even select post and join its tags by join keyword . here is a good tutorial for join tables results https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I created a table called tags and one called post_tags, tags has column 'tag' (tag name ex. computer) and column 'mode' so I can disable certain tags from being shown and stuff, post_tags takes postid,tag so it can be like so entrys can be like '1|windows' and '1|computer' is this a good practice?

Comment: Then for searching for multiple tags do I first find all posts with the first tag then loops through all and see if they have the second tag? Seems like it would cost alot

Comment: both together , select all posts that have first and second and ... tag  . or select posts that has At least one of given tags . this is the common way to organize tags . this relationship is known as the "many to many" .each posts can have many tags, and each tags can belong to many posts

Comment: How would i do it together if each tag on each post has its own post_tags item like '1|computer' then another item '1|windows' its not like i can use WHERE and AND since its two items.

Comment: if you want many to many relation you must create a table for tags . another table for posts and another table for attach posts to tags . see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2923921/7422742

Comment: That helped but I don't get how to search for a post that has two tags?