# Is having relationships to a pivot table a good idea?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Suppose we have the following tables:

**companies**

- id
- name
- ...

**categories**

- id
- name

**category_company**

- category_id
- company_id

Now, for each category the company belongs to we need to store the products they offer for that category. I'm wondering if it's a good idea to add an auto-incrementing primary key to the pivot table and then use that id on the products table as shown below.

**category_company**

- id
- category_id
- company_id

**products**

- id
- category_company_id
- name

Is there a better way to handle this? In the real proyect that I'm working on I have 5 more tables that depend on the category company relationship.

Comment: Your company_id should be unique, so combination of category_id and company_id should also be unique. Why to create an id field for that? No reasons.

Comment: @AndrewShmig Thanks for the feedback, yes company is unique and combination of company_id, catergory_id is unique, but I have other tables that depend on that relationship (Products in the example provided) So should I add the category_id and company_id to the products table or add a primary key to the category_company table and use that key on the other tables.

Comment: Each product could have more than one category?

Comment: Each product belongs to one category and belongs to one company, each product is unique and it's not coming from a list.

Comment: Than it's better to create two fields in product table, than move these fields into new table. Think of future JOINs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other approaches to your problem, but yours is correct too. You may or may not have the id in your category_company table, depending on if you are using some specific framework or ORM, but as @AndrewShmig stated you don't need it. 
IMPORTANT: Remember you are building many-to-many relationships, so you need to add a primary key or unique compound index to 'category_company' table on columns 'category_id' and 'company_id', even if you are keeping the 'id' column. You don't want the same Company listed twice in a Category, or vice versa. 
In MVC model ORM's your approach (with an 'id' in category_company / pivot) is prefered, because you can assign additional information to the relationship itself, treatening your pivot table like another object. 
Is not the same, but think of these two cases:
[image]

[image]

If you are a more Object Oriented programmer, something like the second option may fit your needs (which is kind of what you have), plus you can add extra information for the relationship like 'categorized_by', 'date_of_categorization' or something like that. 
*If you have 5+ tables that depend on that relationship (like 'products'), of course handling the relationship in an intermediate table is way better than to have 'category_id' and 'company_id' fields in each of them. 
Sources:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association
- [Many-to-many relationships examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response, I do believe it makes sense to treat the relation as another object as you mentioned and avoid repetition by declaring the columns on each table. Thanks!