# How to Explode multiple ids in same fields PHP

Tags: php, pdo

The user table is as follows :

## UserTable

```
uid Name    address
1  Ravi    Rajasthan
2  Kamal   Bihar
3  Sunil   Rajasthan
4  Laxman  Punjab
```

The group table is as follows :

## GroupTable

```
gid   gname    users
1     group1   1,3,4
2     group2   2,4
```

I am using This Code.

```
    $sql = "SELECT groups.uid,groups.group_name FROM users
    INNER JOIN users ON users.uid=groups.uid";
    $query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    //$resul = explode(",", $results)
    $cnt=1;
    foreach($results as $result){
        echo '<br>';
    $getids = (explode(',', $result->uid));
    foreach ($getids as $getid) {
    //echo $getid . '<br>';
    $id = $getid;
    $sql = "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE uid=:id";
    $query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':id',$id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    foreach($results as $result)  {
    echo $result->user_name . ', ' ;

        }
    }

}

?>
```

Could anyone explain it to me I am having a hard time in understanding.
Thanks

Comment: In your code, your are exploding `uid` which is a sinle integer without any commas `,` according to your tables.

Comment: There are lots of error in you query. Tell us exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: This is a very bad database design. Check that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/

Answer (score -1):

To get a list of all users per group you can use a **single SQL** query:

```
SELECT
    groups.uid, groups.group_name,
    users.uid, users.user_name
FROM groups
INNER JOIN users ON users.uid IN(groups.users)
```

Comment: This is wrong. SQL doesn't work that way. A string with a comma-separated list is one value. This is not the same as a list of values.