# Is it possible to create tables dynamically in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, mysql-workbench

I was doing a mini project on Cryptocurrency tracking. I have a Users table in Mysql to store the details of registered users in my webapp.
When user logs in, they can see a table of cryptocurrencies. They can add a specific cryptocurrency as favorite from that table by clicking a button.

Now, when they click that button I want to store the id of specific crypto in a table. Since one user can add more than one crypto as their favorite, I can't store the CryptoId in a single cell. So, my requirement is, I need seperate "Favorite" table for every user. Whenever a new User registers, I want to create a new "Favorite" table for that user. How can I achieve this?

Please give me any solution or advice on this, or any alternative Idea on how I can implement this requirement of mine.

Comment: Why would you want a separate table for each instead of a relationship table, which would include columns for both user cryptoCurrency id? And, when you need user's favourites, you would select from the favourites table all records with the particular id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a many-to-many relationship table:

Users:
user_id
username
...

Crypto_Currencies:
cc_id
cc_name

UserCCFaves:
user_id
cc_id

Each time a user adds a favorite, you put a record in UserCCFaves linking the user and the crypto currency

[Many-to-many relationships examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples)