# How can I store user's favourite categories in MySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I store different types of `categories` in a database?

[image: favourite categories list]

Comment: 1. comma-separated string if your criteria are dynamic. 2. Use a criteria table, and have a relation, that "user has many criteria", name the join table favorite_criteria if you like to or criterias_users

Comment: It's called [many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples)

Comment: Can you post here what you have tried?

Comment: @FaizaanKhan comma-separated values should never be an option. Don't encourage people to denormalise their data, it stores up lots of problems for the future

Answer (score 3):

To store User favourite categories of users you need 3 tables named below.. Here I assume that a user can have many favourite categories and a category have many users these types of relationships are called `many-to-Many`Relationships ..**You Can google Many-to-Many relationships to get more informations**

```
users table // to hold user information
id - as primary key
name- 
etc,,
```

and

```
categories table // to hold category information
id - as primary key
name - category name unique
etc,,
```

and another table named `category_users` to hold the `many to many relationship`
the table will hold these columns

```
id- as primary key (optional)
user_id - foreign key (users id)
category_id - foreign key (category id)
```

You Can refer [this many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples)