# Show many to many relationship table in nodejs with mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, arrays

I have the following tables, which have a relationship of many to many. Each project can have many technologies, and each technology can belong to many projects.

```
MariaDB [portfolioDB]> describe Projects_Project;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| projectId   | int(4)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| view        | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| code        | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date        | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [portfolioDB]> describe Projects_Technology;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| technologyID | int(4)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [portfolioDB]> describe Projects_rel_Project_Technology;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Project    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Technology | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

This is how the relationship table was created, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2923921/18895342).

```
CREATE TABLE Projects_rel_Project_Technology (
    Project INT NOT NULL, 
    Technology INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Project, Technology), 
    CONSTRAINT Constr_Projects_rel_Project_Technology_Project_fk FOREIGN KEY Project_fk (Project) REFERENCES Projects_Project(projectId) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT Constr_Projects_rel_Project_Technology_Technology_fk FOREIGN KEY Technology_fk (Technology) REFERENCES Projects_Technology(technologyID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

With this query I can get all the technologies that belong to a specified project, which is what I need for node.

```
SELECT Projects_Technology.* FROM Projects_Technology JOIN Projects_rel_Project_Technology ON Projects_Technology.technologyID = Projects_rel_Project_Technology.Technology WHERE Projects_rel_Project_Technology.Project = 1;
```

This is the node code, actually I can get all the data from the projects in a list.

```
app.get("/api/showProjects", function (request, response){
    mysqlConnectionStart();

    var myquery = `select * from Projects_Project`;

    connection.query(myquery, function(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('----> Error with MySQL query in /showProjects: ' + err.message);
        }
        else{
            console.log('Query successful, results for "' + myquery + '" are being displayed.');
            
            var mylist = [];

            Object.keys(results).forEach(function(key) {
                var row = results[key];
                mylist.push({ 
                    'projectId' : row.projectId,
                    'name' : row.name,
                    'description' : row.description,
                    'view' : row.view,
                    'code' : row.code,
                    'date' : row.date
                });
            });

            response.send({"My projects" : mylist});
        }
    });


    mysqlConnectionEnd();
});
```

[image: Json data]

So the final question is that I don't know how to insert the query (the posted one) to get the technologies that belong to a project in the project data, because I can get them OR get the project data, can't get both.

mylist.push should be like this at the end I think

```
var arr_technologies = [];
Object.keys(results).forEach(function(key) {
    var row = results[key];
    arr_technologies.push({
        'name' : row.name
    });
}
mylist.push({ 
    'projectId' : row.projectId,
    'name' : row.name,
    'description' : row.description,
    'view' : row.view,
    'code' : row.code,
    'date' : row.date,
    'technologies' : arr_technologies
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join all 3 tables. You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get a comma-separated list of technology names for each project. Then you can use `split()` to split it into an array.

There's also no need to use `Object.keys(results)`. `results` is an array, you can loop over it directly with `map()` or `forEach()`.

```js
app.get("/api/showProjects", function(request, response) {
  mysqlConnectionStart();

  var myquery = `
    SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(pt.name) AS technologies 
    FROM Projects_Project AS p
    JOIN Projects_rel_Project_Technology AS prpt ON prpt.Project = p.ProjectID
    JOIN Projects_Technology AS pt ON pt.technologyID = prpt.Technology
    GROUP BY p.ProjectID;`;

  connection.query(myquery, function(err, results, fields) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('----> Error with MySQL query in /showProjects: ' + err.message);
      } else {
        console.log('Query successful, results for "' + myquery + '" are being displayed.');

        var mylist = results.map(row => ({
            'projectId': row.projectId,
            'name': row.name,
            'description': row.description,
            'view': row.view,
            'code': row.code,
            'date': row.date,
            'techology': row.technologies.split(',')
          })
        });

      response.send({
        "My projects": mylist
      });
    }
  });

mysqlConnectionEnd();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't fully understand `map()` yet and the `Object.keys(results)` is from another tutorial.