# Retrieve array from database and show it as a list, php laravel

Tags: php, laravel-blade

related_members Table

| ID | related_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["4","5"] |
| 2 | ["1","3"] |

I have a db like this, and I would like to retrieve that related_id in to a list, in a laravel blade. My PHP is very limited. Please help.

```
@foreach(\App\Models\Member::all()->where('related_id', $member->related_id) as $users )
    <li>{{ $users['related_id']}}</li>
@endforeach
```

It returns ["4","5"]

But I want
4
5
as a list.

Comment: Please normalize your database where one row will have `id | related_id` (e.g. `1 | 4`, `1 | 5`, etc.) or other M-M relation. Now you have to json decode your `related_id` and only than loop it

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`array` cast](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) on your `Member` model. The cast will preprocess the `related_id` and transform it into an array.

To use a cast, simply add a protected property `$casts`, to your model, and assign it an associative array with the keys being the property you want to cast and the value the cast:

```php
class Member extends Model {
  /** ... **/
  protected $casts = [
    'related_id' => 'array'
  ];
  /** ... **/
}
```

As a side note, it is not a good idea to store ids in a list, in your database. You are missing on many important feature that the database offer, like foreign key validation for example.

Depending on your case, you might want to create a *many-to-many* relationship between your `members` table and the table that contains the value you want to link via the `related_ids`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2923921/5784924) gives a good example on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I should create a many-to-may relationship.