# How to assign multiple Foreign keys to one box in an sql table

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have created a database that has one table that keeps track of employee skills and another which displays projects that these employees can be assigned to.

I need to have multiple employees asigned to the same project but I do not know how I would do this, and when I try to use a query to fill in this space with anything that meets these requirements, I get an error for returning multiple rows.

Here is the query code:

```
UPDATE projects
SET POOL_ID = (
SELECT skills.POOL_ID
FROM skills
WHERE skills.Skill_Name = 'JavaScript'
    AND skills.POOL_ID IS NOT NULL
)
WHERE PROJECT_ID = 1;
```

Thanks for any help, I am new to SQL and as such dont know if this is even possible but I've googled it and cannot find any help there and I've also tried adjusting the query etc.

Comment: You need a third table that holds the many-to-many relationship between projects and employees.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples

Comment: It would be helpful if you updated your question (using editable text) to show sample data for the tables and the result you are trying to achieve. At the moment it’s not obvious how the SQL you’ve given relates to what you are asking